# Combining data frames with the same columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
A B C
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

And also another data frame that looks like this

```
A B C
2 1 7
4 3 9
6 5 8
```

How can I combine those two data frames to get a new data frame that looks like this

```
A B C
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
2 1 7
4 3 9
6 5 8
```

Basically, the two data frames have the same column names and number of columns. I just want to combine all of the rows. Would prefer using pandas to do this.

Comment: you can use concat. `df = pd.concat([df1,df2])`

Comment: @rhug123, please post that as an answer. This is simple solution and you have already answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `append`

```
df1 = df1.append(df2)
```